# System.ExternalObjectException

Tags: apex, lightning-connect, external

we are facing issue with external objects.

Scenario -

1. we have external data source and using oAuth2.0 as Authentication protocol and using custom auth provider which will manage refresh access tokens.
2. Now whenever access token is expired, SF will automatically get the latest token and makes callout to external system and callout is success 200- and getting required response as well - but at the end of transaction we are receiving exception as : **System.ExternalObjectException: We encountered an unexpected error. Try again later, or contact your administrator, who can verify the external data source settings and the external system's availability. Error received from the external system:** and XDS_RESPONSE is showing a message as **message:java.lang.NullPointerException : null**
3. when accesstoken is valid, we are not facing any issues. Issue is coming only when access token is expired.

Any help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to solve this error?